# PhpMyAdmin doesn't encrypted on login

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, ssl

I have server on DO. I already use ssl https. On url showing my ssl was running but when I login to my phpmyadmin, why login information showing without encrypted?
I also add `$cfg['ForceSSL'] = true;` but nothing happen.
Can someone help?

You can see here [image]

My problem: pma_username etc not encrypted, as you can see on the pict.

I also use auth_type cookie

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In addition to the other information that Community Bot asked for, please also let us know which auth_type you are using.

Comment: I use cookie for auth_type